# How to load a sequence of elliptic Fourier coefficients into R to make an outline analysis in Momocs package?

Tags: r, fourier-descriptors

I'm novice with R.

I have a text file with precalculated sequence of elliptic Fourier coefficients (harmonics). The first column keeps the objects name, other - sets of harmonics divides by spaces: A0 B0 C0 D0 ... An Bn Cn Dn. It is the  part of a file:

```
Lceph-sp1-1    0    0,27    -1    0    -0,29    0,2    0,1    -0,05    0,15    0,1    0,07    0,02
Lceph-sp1-2    0    -0,36    1    0    -0,27    0,25    0,12    -0,09    -0,26    -0,03    -0,17    0
Lceph-sp1-3    0    0,25    -1    0    -0,29    0,19    0,09    -0,05    0,15    0,1    0,06    0,01
Lceph-sp1-4    0    -0,37    1    0    -0,27    0,26    0,09    -0,07    -0,19    -0,07    -0,12    -0,02
```

I load file into R with the **read.delim2** command:

```
ef <- read.delim2( "filename", header=FALSE, sep="")
```

Then I want to analyze obtained data using functions from [Momocs package](https://github.com/vbonhomme/Momocs/), like **calibrate_harmonicpower**, **plot**, **PCA** and other.

To do so it is necessary to transform loaded data into Coe(?) or other object. (I don't exactly know to which one.)

How to prepare loaded data for analysis in Momocs R package?

Answer (score 2):

If you calculates elliptical Fourier coefficients outside R/Momocs, then you must import them as an `OutCoe` object as follows:

```
# we load Momocs and import your table.
library(Momocs)

#Here I use your data (using `text` but a path to your file will work by your side
data <- read.table(dec=",", text="
Lceph-sp1-1    0    0,27    -1    0    -0,29    0,2    0,1    -0,05    0,15    0,1    0,07    0,02
Lceph-sp1-2    0    -0,36    1    0    -0,27    0,25    0,12    -0,09    -0,26    -0,03    -0,17    0
Lceph-sp1-3    0    0,25    -1    0    -0,29    0,19    0,09    -0,05    0,15    0,1    0,06    0,01
Lceph-sp1-4    0    -0,37    1    0    -0,27    0,26    0,09    -0,07    -0,19    -0,07    -0,12    -0,02")

# we can extract the `$fac` cofactor/variates table with `lf_structure`
fac <- lf_structure(data[, 1], names=c("ind", "sp", "id"), split="-")

# then we simply pass all columns but the first, the `fac` 
# and two others arguments `Momocs` cannot deduce `method` and `norm`
# see ?Outcoe
x <- OutCoe(coe=data[, -1], fac=fac, method="efourier", norm=TRUE)
```

We now have a 'working' `Outcoe` object:

```
> x
An OutCoe object [ elliptical Fourier analysis ]
--------------------
  - $coe: 4 outlines described, 3 harmonics
- $fac: 3 classifiers:
  'ind' (factor 1): Lceph.
'sp' (factor 1): sp1.
'id' (factor 4): 1, 2, 3, 4.
```

That you can use to continue your analyses, eg:

```
x %>% PCA %>% plot
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: and sorry for the delay, haven't seen this before.